# error creating kafka client: kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to: unexpected EOF" while creating KEDA scaled object

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, keda

We are trying to setup keda service for scale up/down of our pods based on events from kafka. However, when we try to create scaled object we get the error. Could anyone please help here.

Note ; We have created secrets, trigger authentication and scaled object.

```
2023-03-14T03:30:58Z    ERROR   Reconciler error    {"controller": "scaledobject", "controllerGroup": "keda.sh", "controllerKind": "ScaledObject", "scaledObject": {"name":"kafka-scale","namespace":"keda-test"}, "namespace": "keda-test", "name": "kafka-scale", "reconcileID": "341615d9-b762-43ba-a3e0-1d680baaf75e", "error": "error creating kafka client: kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to: unexpected EOF"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).processNextWorkItem
```

---

```
Status:
  Conditions:
    Message:               Failed to ensure HPA is correctly created for ScaledObject
    Reason:                ScaledObjectCheckFailed
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
    Message:               ScaledObject check failed
    Reason:                UnkownState
    Status:                Unknown
    Type:                  Active
    Status:                Unknown
    Type:                  Fallback
  Original Replica Count:  1
  Scale Target GVKR:
    Group:            apps
    Kind:             Deployment
    Resource:         deployments
    Version:          v1
  Scale Target Kind:  apps/v1.Deployment
Events:
  Type     Reason                   Age                 From           Message
  ----     ------                   ----                ----           -------
  Warning  ScaledObjectCheckFailed  79s (x12 over 98s)  keda-operator  Failed to ensure HPA is correctly created for ScaledObject
  Warning  KEDAScalerFailed         68s (x13 over 98s)  keda-operator  error creating kafka client: kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to: unexpected EOF

We have created secrets, trigger authentication and scaled object.

ScaledObject.yaml

apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-03-14T03:24:25Z"
  finalizers:
  - finalizer.keda.sh
  generation: 1
  labels:
    scaledobject.keda.sh/name: kafka-scale
  name: kafka-scale
  namespace: sachin
  resourceVersion: "51327064"
  uid: <uid>
spec:
  pollingInterval: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: sachin-pod-test
  triggers:
  - authenticationRef:
      name: keda-trigger-auth-kafka-credential
    metadata:
      bootstrapServers: <list of brokers>
      consumerGroup: sachin
      lagThreshold: "1"
      topic: sachin_test
    type: kafka
```

Comment: Hi, i'm facing the same issue as well. Wonder if you managed to resolve this.